# Fourth div not showing up unless others are set to display: none

Tags: css, html

So I am making a little site just for fun - and to learn HTML a little better.

I have four divs. I want the to be arranged kind of like a collage. I have three of them in the perfect positions, but the fourth one does not show up at all unless I make the other three invisible with display:none in the CSS...

Anyone know why this would happen? Im using Chromium on Ubuntu.

```
<body>
  <center>
    <div id="content1">

    </div>
    <div id="content2">

    </div>
    <div id="content3">

    </div>
    <div id="cont4">
    THIS ONE DOESN'T SHOW UP.
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#content1{
    width:230px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:10px;
    position: relative;
    left: -240px;
}
#content2{
    width:230px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:red;   
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position: relative;
    left: -240px;
}
#content3{
    width:230px;
    height: 520px;
    background-color:red;   
    border-radius:10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
}
#cont4{
    width:230px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:purple;    
    position: relative;
    left: 240px;
}
```

Comment: `center` is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: haha, i try to read too fast , I swore I saw <div class="center">

Comment: @user802609 - it shows up, its just way down there

Comment: that 4th div is shown at the right bottom of document. There is reserved empty space for the 3rd div due to its relative position. Look also here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3VBN/1/

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw in Chrome and Firefox, cont4 is showing up, but it's way down on the page (you have to scroll to see it). I don't know exactly where you want it, but adding top: -1040px aligns it at the top of the page with the rest of the divs.

```css
#cont4{
    width:230px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:purple;    
    position: relative;
    left: 240px;
    top: -1040px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `#cont4` a `top: -1040px;`. This means, for the previous div, you applied a `-520px` top to make it align top. So `this lengh` + `height of that div` (520+520=1040) is required for your purple div to appear. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/MpjRM/2/)*** is the demo.

But this is not my solution. Use `margin-top: -520px;` instead of `top: -520px;` to your third div. This will shift the fourth div along with the third div. But `top` wont do this. `top` is for tweak an element with use of `position` property. `margin-top` is for measuring the external distance to the element, in relation to the previous one.

Also, top behavior can differ depending on the type of position, absolute, relative or fixed.

Here is the corrected **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/MpjRM/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The tag `center` is deprecated as Jared Farrish said. Actually, you should use CSS more carefully to get this types of layouts. There are lots of example is available. Trying to search with "*Multi Column Layout with CSS*". You can check [THIS](http://www.ozzu.com/html-tutorials/tutorial-multi-column-layout-using-css-float-part-t85704.html) tutorial.

Also, [THIS](http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp) is very useful resource. [THIS](http://www.pagecolumn.com/) tool is interesting one. You can check this as well.